# How to clone repo as folder only

Tags: git, directory, clone, chef-infra, bitbucket

Struggling to find the answer to this. I've cloned the blank chef-repo at opscode. I want to keep this in my own infrastructure repo. I tried deleting .git folder, no good :S (really thought that would have been the solution). I tried using as submodule, also no good.

It links me to the github repo when I try to click the folder on bitbucket.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What is the exact outcome you're looking for?

Comment: I want to be able to clone the chef-repo, use it in my own repo as a folder (not git ignored because of its repo-ness). I want the changes in it to be tracked. They aren't picked up by git status from the parent folder. So currently, I have no way of saving the changes that I have made to the chef-repo. It is not tracked by the parent repo.

I would rather not have the chef-repo as a repo in my bitbucket, it would be nicer to just have the one infrastructure repo.

Comment: Use git submodule: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `chef-repo` skeleton, Chef now ships with a command to generate the skeleton yourself: [`chef generate app APP_NAME`](https://docs.getchef.com/ctl_chef.html#chef-generate-app)